# Expo SDK32 undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expo2.default.KeepAwake')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, expo

I upgraded expo for my React Native App from SDK25 to SDK32 directly following the steps explained on the Expo Documentation.
When i try to run the app into the Expo client, i get the following error

> `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expo2.default.KeepAwake')
>   <unknown>
>       crna-entry.js:20:17
>   loadModuleImplementation
>       require.js:292:12
>   guardedLoadModule
>       require.js:179:45
>   global code
>       <unknown file>:0`

**Environment**

- Expo CLI 2.6.14
- Node: 10.0.0
- npm: 6.5.0
- expo: ^32.0.0 => 32.0.0
- react: 16.5.0 => 16.5.0
- react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz 
  => 0.57.1
- react-navigation: ^3.0.9 => 3.0.9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove react-native-scripts and update main key

Comment: What do you mean by this? Remove react-native-scripts? Aren't they all react native scripts?  and how do you updated the main key?

Comment: @AngelGarcia The error had gone after modifying like below in "package.json".

(old)
"main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
(new)
"main": "./node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading your project to use Expo CLI.

Make these changes to `package.jso`n:

Replace `react-native-scripts` with `expo` in the `scripts` config.
Example:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "test": "jest"
}
```

Remove `react-native-scripts` from `devDependencies`.

Change the `main` key to `node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js` then run `npm start -- -c`